# WPF time dropdown box with objectdataprovider

Tags: wpf, xaml, time, combobox, objectdataprovider

I'm trying to implement a user control for choosing time with 3 comboboxes - one for hours, second for minutes and third for seconds.

Hours' combobox has numbers from 0 to 23 to choose from

Minutes' and seconds' combobox has numbers 0 to 59 to choose from

I believe I can do it just with XAML without needing to fill the comboboxes dynamically in the codebehind.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="HoursComboBox">
    <ComboBoxItem>0</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    ...
    <ComboBoxItem>23</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

But this looks like a lot of static and unneccessary code. I can fill the combobox with just one line in the codebehind like this.

```
HoursComboBox.ItemsSource = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 23);
```

Can I implement this call just in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I can.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControls.TimeSpanSelector"
             xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
             ...>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Hours"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type linq:Enumerable}"
                            MethodName="Range">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
                <sys:Int32>23</sys:Int32>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    ...

    <Border>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Hours}}" />
    </Border>

    ...

</UserControl>
```